# How to update password in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I did the registration/Login on my Razor Pages. But I want to do some sort of "Edit Profile" Page in my blazor Server App component. So initially my idea was to get the UserName via AuthenticationStateTask.Result.User.Identity.Name and just do something like a Update Where UserName = ...Identity.Name via a stored procedure. However after some research it turns out its not as easy as I thought.

After some research I thought I could reset the password to a new password via the code snippet below. However I run into many walls. Such as var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(NewNameModel.LoginId); returning a null object even though I checked that the string is a valid username and also if I do FindByIdAsync I get more lost as I have no idea how to access my Id value.

I would like to know if anybody has insights on how to do a update password for Blazor?

```html
    public async Task ChangePasswordValidSubmit()
    {

        NewNameModel.LoginId = AuthenticationStateTask.Result.User.Identity.Name;
        Console.WriteLine($"LoginId: {NewNameModel.LoginId}");

        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(NewNameModel.LoginId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User not found.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User found.");
        }

        var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        Console.WriteLine($"Token: {token}");

        var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, NewPasswordModel.NewPassword);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password changed successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password change failed:");
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error.Description}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: UserManager is a service.  You can inject it in your markup with `@inject UserManager UM` and access it in your code with `UM.FindByNameAsync(xyz)` etc.

Comment: That's what I did. 

var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(NewNameModel.LoginId);

But I get null reference for user.

Comment: What I said and what you said are not in fact the same thing.

Comment: Is the user name an email? You could try `FindByNameAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public async Task ChangePasswordValidSubmit()
   {

       NewNameModel.LoginId = AuthenticationStateTask.Result.User.Identity.Name;
       var currentId = AuthenticationStateTask.Result.User.Identity.Name;
       var user = await um.FindByNameAsync(currentId);

       var token = await um.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

       var result = await um.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, NewPasswordModel.NewPassword);

       if (result.Succeeded)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Password changed successfully");
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Password change failed:");
           foreach (var error in result.Errors)
           {
               Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error.Description}");
           }
       }
   }
```

did as suggested and used FindByNameAsync to populate the user var.